# Cannot select Page tab platform: "this platform cannot be listed" - Facebook app

Tags: facebook

I'm developing an app for a customer so before launching it on the production website and on the customer FB page, I want to **try it out** on a page of mine.

I'm not interested at all in publishing this app to the FB App center: **I just want to be able to make it a tab of a fan page that I administer.**

For the same reason I'm not using a real https server for the secure canvas URL: instead,  I'm using the workaround described [here](http://blog.almabase.com/post/84579042935/a-hack-for-facebook-secure-canvas-url-requirement).

My problem is: from the `App details` page, in the `App Center Listed Platforms` section, the option `Page tab` is greyed out (see picture) and I keep getting a not-at-all-self-explaining error like:

`This platform cannot be listed because it is either configured incorrectly or not supported in App Center.`

[FB documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines) didn't get me any help, this error is not mentioned.

[image: facebook app details screenshot]

**What should I do to make the "Page Tab" option selectable?**

What I've done so far:

1. set up 2 platforms: Canvas and Tab (anyway, using Tab only doesn't make any difference)
2. uploaded **all** the required pictures, in the correct sizes (it's been a pain)
3. created a test user from the `Roles` page > `Test user` tab
4. created a test App from the `Test apps` page
5. **important**: specified two app domains (the one I uploaded my app to, and `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`)
6. specified a valid contact email, a page tab URL and a page tab secure URL

Comment: If you don't wand to be in App Center don't submit your App Details.

Comment: @WizKid from the "status and review" page, I turned off the option saying "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?". This didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes. I said don't submit App Details.

Comment: @WizKid please can you elaborate a bit? What should I or shouldn't I do, and why? What should I expect to happen?

Comment: That workaround will not work. You are not allowed to redirect away from a page tab app

Comment: @Paolo Stefan could you solve this problem finally? It's exactly my problem now.

Comment: @LonelyDeveloper no, I gave up. WizKid has answered, in one of the above comments, that it's not possible.